# Setting HTTP header (like expire) on Play Result - and how to handle ETag?

Tags: playframework

How can I set Http headers in the result object in play 2.0?

I want to set Cache control (expire) ala this:
Cache-Control
PUBLIC, max-age=2592000

What is the best way to check the ET tag and return the correct response ?

have been looking through here, but didnt see anything:
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/JavaActions

In advance thanks
thomas vervik

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to take a look at the JavaResponse section...

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/JavaResponse

An example of setting cache control from the documentation is

```
public static Result index() {
  response().setContentType("text/html");
  response().setHeader(CACHE_CONTROL, "max-age=3600");
  response().setHeader(ETAG, "xxx");
  return ok("<h1>Hello World!</h1>");
}
```

Comment: also found a good link to server the static assets

https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/Assets