# Play Framework 2.4 - Java - Http header and cached response

Tags: java, caching, playframework, header, cache-control

I have a problem to send header for a cached response.

Here's my routes,

```
 GET    /fassets/XXX.js  com.AssetController.getFileXXX()
```

And my controller,

```
@Cached(key = XXX, duration = TIMEOUT_SECONDS,)
public Result getFileXXX() {

[...]
final Result result = ok(file).as("application/javascript");
response().setHeader(CACHE_CONTROL, "max-age=100");
return result;
}
```

The problem is that for the first request, cache-control : max-age=100 is correctly sended. 
For the others, the result is cached and the header is not set.

I tryed

```
result.headers().put(CACHE_CONTROL, "max-age=10")
```

But that lead to a runtime error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
at java.util.AbstractMap.put(AbstractMap.java:209) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
```

I also found something interesting that could have solved the problem, but in scala :

```
val result = Ok("Hello World!").withHeaders(CACHE_CONTROL -> "max-age=3600")
```

Thanks by advance for your help.

**Julien**

Comment: So what exactly is the issue/problem/behavior that you want?

Comment: I want to have the cache-control header sent with the cached response.
Here, the response is sent from the @Cached without adding the header.

I finally resolved my problem by using the cache.get/set instead of anotating. So I can set the header each time.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [answer by Codemwnci](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10565734/873282) also applies to your question:

You need to take a look at the [JavaResponse section](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaResponse#Setting-HTTP-response-headers).

An example of setting cache control from the documentation is

```
public static Result index() {
  response().setContentType("text/html");
  response().setHeader(CACHE_CONTROL, "max-age=3600");
  response().setHeader(ETAG, "xxx");
  return ok("<h1>Hello World!</h1>");
}
```

I would set the `response().setHeader` things before a call to `ok`.